# Elasticsearch k8s (eck-operator) nodeSets config does not work

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, cloud

I am trying to configure cluster elasticsearch using eck-operator. I would like to add some settings like `cluster.max.shards.per.node` and others available in legacy in `elasticsearch.yaml`.
I tried to add this to elasticsearch instance the manifest in the section:

```
nodeSets: 
     - node: default
       config: 
         cluster_max.shards.per.node: 3000
```

but without successfully.
Is it possible it that way? I could not find any support and documentation how to use config and what possible properties are available.

Answer (score 0):

Some cluster-level settings don't take effect unless they're set via the Cluster Settings API, and values specified in elasticsearch.yml are ignored.

The cluster.max_shards_per_node issue has been fixed in [#57234](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/57234). Because cluster.blocks.read_only is highly unlikely to be set via the YAML config.

For more information refer to this [issue](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/problem-with-cluster-max-shards-per-node-setting/190933/3) and [git link](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/40803).

Comment: Yes, I also found this tasks before. I thought maybe I do this in wrong way. But anyway, is there any documentation how to add properties from legacy to k8s? Is it ok in nodeSets section in manifest? 
For example I also want to auto create 2 indices: filebeat-* and apm-* during cluster startup. I also need to add this by API? Same for log level and few other settings. 
I can do same during docker image preparation but of course better and profesional and usefull is to set them in k8s values.

Comment: Attaching supporting docs which can help you [Api](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/), [elastic search](https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-to-manage-elasticsearch-data-multiple-indices-filebeat-ilm-data-streams)